# Gradle plugin configuration in kotlin script

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to configure Kotlin net.researchgate.release plugin. I have following setup (kts script):

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("net.researchgate.release") version "2.8.1"
}
```

In the same script I'm trying to configure plugin:

```
release {
    svn {
        username = "some"
        password = System.getenv("SOME")
        pinExternals = false
    }
}
```

During build I've got:

```
Unresolved reference: svn
```

How would I configure this plugin?

Comment: I suspect this might be because there is no type-safe accessor for it. I can't test this right now, but could you try writing it like "svn" (in double quotes)

Comment: Expression '"svn"' of type 'String' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found.
IDE also going mad about release keyword. Looks like I'm doing something wrong. Should I wrap somehow "release"?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html Example 3. Artifact configurations might have something for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin does not support the Kotlin DSL. The reason is that it uses Groovy meta-programming constructs to configure the nested extensions, and you are not using Groovy.

There are two open issues for this problem: [281](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release/issues/281) and [288](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release/issues/288). The former suggests a few different work-arounds, including configuring the SVN adapter like this:

```
release {
    with (propertyMissing("svn") as SvnAdapter.SvnConfig) {
        username = "some"
        // etc...
    }
}
```